# Subgroups of special linear group SL$(n, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, linear-groups

> Are there characterizations of subgroups of a special linear group SL$(n, \mathbb{Z})$?

Since SL$(n, \mathbb{Z})$ has infinite order, it would be enough if I know how to generate subgroups of SL$(n, \mathbb{Z}_p)$. Here, $n$ is rather large.

Comment: I don't think; even consider weaker question: *Determine finite subgroups of $SL_n(Z)$.* I had seen answer for this on MathOverflow only for some small values of $n$.

Comment: Even for $\;n=2\;$ this can be hard to do, since $\;SL(2,\Bbb Z)\;$ already contains a free subgroup with finite index. You may want to check the excellent "Algebra IV: Infinite Groups, Linear Groups" , Edited by Kostrikin and Shafarevich

Comment: Even finding the maximal subgroups of ${\rm SL}(n,p)$ is not easy for large $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a characterization of *finite-index* subgroups of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ as follows:

*Theorem (Mennicke)* For $n\ge 3$ every finite-index subgroup of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is a [congruence subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup).

This is not true for $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, where we have a veritable zoo of finite-index subgroups, as $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\cong C_2\ast_{C_2}C_3$ contains a free subgroup of finite index.